# Where to put custom validation function inside CouchApp folder structure?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchapp

Where in CouchApp folder structure should I put [validation function](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/validation.html) that it will be properly pushed with `couchapp push` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [CouchApp documentation](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp/wiki/Complete-Filesystem-to-Design-Doc-Mapping-Example).

The correct file is `./validate_doc_update.js`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that!